# Disable Helvetica in Google Chrome on windows

Tags: windows, google-chrome, fonts

Installing the Helvetica family of fonts lead to [problems](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/InstallingHelveticaNeueFontsWithGoogleChromeOnWindowsConsideredHarmful.aspx) for Google Chrome. Previously, this can be solved by using custom.css to forcefully use Arial,

```
@font-face { font-family: 'helvetica neue'; src: local('Arial'); }
@font-face { font-family: 'helvetica neue'; font-weight:bold; src: local('Arial'); }
@font-face { font-family: 'helvetica'; src: local('Arial'); }
@font-face { font-family: 'helvetica'; font-weight:bold; src: local('Arial'); }
```

However, costom.css was diabled in recent builds of Google Chrome. Suppose I need to keep the Helvetica fonts, is there a way to deal with this problem now?

Answer (score 1):

The custom.css solution can be used with the [Stylish Chrome Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylish/fjnbnpbmkenffdnngjfgmeleoegfcffe).